# Google CSE query terms with wildcards

Tags: google-custom-search

I've tried to look in the official documentation but to no avail.

In the documentation for Google search appliance, https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/50/xml_reference#query_term_separators, I noticed that wildcards (i.e. *) are not supported, is this also the case with CSE?

Is there anyway around this, or are there any viable alternatives to CSE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wildcards are supported with CSE.

Here is a link to search results for "wildcards" on Google's custom search support: https://support.google.com/customsearch/search?q=wildcards

Comment: The link that you posted is about using wildcards on URL's that you wanted to include in the index, not wildcards in the search query